# Disable omnibox search engine change suggestions in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines, google-search

Is there a way not to let Chrome suggest me to change omnibox search engine from "google.com" (which I want to have) to "google.??" (like google.ca, google.cz etc.) with a yellow bubble-like message (see below)? I get this message quite often and I have no clue how Chrome detects whether to make that offer or not, probably based on my search keywords... anyways, it bugs a user a lot. My geo location and language is Czech.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chrome detects your location by your ip. Do these to block any site from detecting your location:

1. Click on the wrench icon (top right)
2. Click on Settings
3. Go to "Under the Hood" -> Privacy -> "Content Settings"
4. Find the "Location" section and check "Do not allow any site to track my     physical location"
5. Close "Content Settings"
6. Close Settings tab

[More about sharing location on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en)